# How to align equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I am trying to write a set of equations similar to some found in a book I am reading. Below is how the book has formatted the equations:

[image: book equations]

and here is what I have so far:

[image: my equations]

How can I align my equations so that "maximize" and "subject to" are aligned, while also aligning the sums? I do not want to display "(KP)" or any equation numbers on the side.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \text{maximize} \sum_{j=1}^{n}p_j x_j \\
    \text{subject to} \sum_{j=1}^{n}w_j x_j \leq c, \\
    x_j \in \{0,1\}, j = 1, \ldots, n.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: use the `align` or `align*` environments from the AMS packages, with `&\null` as your separator and `\text{}` for text.

Comment: You could look at [A macro for optimization problems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98141/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: output]

Use the `align` environments from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \text{maximize} &\null \sum_{j=1}^n p_j x_j \\
  \text{subject to} &\null \sum_{j=1}^n w_j x_j \leq c, \\
  &\null x_j \in \{0, 1\}, \quad j=1,\dots,n.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Same solution as mine, but some seconds faster.

Comment: @BenediktBauer Although I wonder if taking out `\null` and aligning at `\sum` is better -- I'm not sure.  (Perhaps even aligning at a spacer like `\;`?)

Comment: Hm, now I see there's a slight difference between your and my solution. I aligned at the sum sign. This will surely be no problem as long as the super- and subscripts are not wider. We would have to check what happens if those are wider than the sum sign. Things might get uglier in this case.

Answer (score 3):

## The simple solution

As long as the super- and subscripts of the summation signs are narrower than the sign itself, the solution is quite simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\text{maximize } &\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_j x_j \\
    \text{subject to } &\sum_{j=1}^{n}w_j x_j \leq c, \\
    &x_j \in \{0,1\}, j = 1, \ldots, n.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## The more sophisticated solution

As soon as one of the super- or subscripts gets wider than the sign, this will break the alignment (note eq. (2)):

```
\begin{align}
\text{maximize } &\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_j x_j \\
    \text{subject to } &\sum_{j=10000}^{n}w_j x_j \leq c, \\
    &x_j \in \{0,1\}, j = 1, \ldots, n.
\end{align}
```

As everything is aligned at the most left part after the `&` sign, the alignment happens in eq. (2) at the "j" subscript, making the sum signs no longer stand right below each other:

[image]

But there is help! The `mathtools` package provides a command called `\mathclap` that in principle sets the box width of its argument to zero (for exact explanation cf. http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf). If we use this, the alignment will work even if the descriptors of the sum sign are wider than the sign itself, by allowing the descriptors to slide over the alignment barrier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\text{maximize } &\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_j x_j \\
    \text{subject to } &\sum_{\mathclap{j=10000}}^{n}w_j x_j \leq c, \\
    &x_j \in \{0,1\}, j = 1, \ldots, n.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  text & equation\\
  text & equation\\
       & equatin
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Additionally, with `alignat`, you can specify multiple alignment points.  If we had 3, we could align equations like this:

```
f(x) & = & x^2 +2x + 1\\
     & = & (x + 1)^2
```

Or you could go with even more alignment options depending on your needs.

[image]

Comment: Could you flesh this out a bit?  Maybe with a MWE and a picture?

Comment: @SeanAllred there you go.