# how to do to align a series of equations

Tags: equations, alignment

how can I make the following equation align?

here is my equation

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\def\ds{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}

    \begin{eqnarray}
     \mbox{Minimize }\quad  F(x,y) = (F_(x,y),F_2(x,y)) && \\
     \mbox{Subject To }\quad  \ds \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m x_{ijk} = 1, && 1\le i\le n \label{constr1} \\
     \ds \sum_{j=0}^n x_{jik} = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} x_{ijk} && 1 \le i\le n,\; 1\le k\le m \label{constr2}\\
     \ds \sum_{j=1}^n x_{0jk} \le 1, && 1\le k\le m \label{constr3}\\
     \ds \sum_{j=1}^n t_{ijk} +s_j \le D_k, && 0\le i\le n,\; 1\le k \le m \label{constr4}\\
     \ds y_{ijk} \le x_{ijk} \times Q_k, && 0\le i,j \le n, \; 1\le k \le m \label{constr5}\\
     \ds x_{ijk} \in \{0,1\}, && 0\le i \le n, \; 0\le j \le n+1,\; 1\le k \le m\label{constr6}\\
     \ds y_{ijk} \ge 0, && 0\le i \le n, \; 0\le j \le n+1,\; 1\le k \le m. \label{constr7}
    \end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

i want it to look like this picture[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to small, compilable document. Where is defined `\ds`?

Comment: \def\ds{\displaystyle}  in package mathtools

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120096/how-to-align-equations.

Comment: @Chamanga, I ask you for MWE (Minimal worling example. Please edit your question and extend your code fragment to complete small document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

With use of the `alignat` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
%\def\ds{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{3}
\text{Minimize}\qquad
    &   F(x,y) = (F_(x,y),F_2(x,y)) 
        &&       \\
\text{Subject To}\qquad
    &   \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m x_{ijk} = 1,
        &&   1\le i\le n                        \label{constr1} \\
    &   \sum_{j=0}^n x_{jik} = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} x_{ijk} 
        &&   1 \le i\le n,\; 1\le k\le m        \label{constr2} \\
    &   \sum_{j=1}^n x_{0jk} \le 1, 
        &&   1\le k\le m                        \label{constr3} \\
    &   \sum_{j=1}^n t_{ijk} +s_j \le D_k, 
        &&   0\le i\le n,\; 1\le k \le m        \label{constr4} \\
    &   y_{ijk} \le x_{ijk} \times Q_k, 
        &&   0\le i,j \le n, \; 1\le k \le m    \label{constr5} \\
    &   x_{ijk} \in \{0,1\}, 
        &&   0\le i \le n, \; 0\le j \le n+1,\; 1\le k \le m    \label{constr6} \\
    &   y_{ijk} \ge 0, 
        &&   0\le i \le n, \; 0\le j \le n+1,\; 1\le k \le m.   \label{constr7}
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```