# Align a linear program

Tags: math-mode, align

I want to write my linear program so that it looks like in this picture: [image: integer program]

meaning I want to have the following:

- text aligned to the left
- all the `x_{j}` variables to be one another
- the `i=` and `j=` statement to be again to be one under the other

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{minimize} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m} w_{j}*&x_{j} \\
\text{subject to} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j:e_{i} \in S_{j}} &x_{j} \geq 1, i=1 ,..., n\\
                                         &x_{j} \in \{0,1\}, j=1 ,..., m
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I tried using multiple `&`s, but either I use them and nothing changes, or I get the following error: `Extra alingment tab has been changed to \cr \end{split}`. I have searched this error and I know that it appeares if I forget to write a `&` or I have an extra one, but this is not my case. This is the code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\text{minimize} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m} w_{j}*&x_{j} & \\
&\text{subject to} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j:e_{i} \in S_{j}} &x_{j} \geq 1, &i=1 ,..., n\\
&                                             &x_{j} \in \{0,1\}, &j=1 ,..., m
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

How can I align them in the way that I want?

And also is it possible to do it without `align`? Because this program is at the end of my page and if I use `align` it gets placed on the next page and I don't want that.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97942/using-an-array-environment-inside-an-xparse-command help? See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98141/a-macro-for-optimization-problems

Comment: I find no reason for having `x_{j}` aligned horizontally.

Comment: How do you think it should be aligned?

Comment: I think it should be aligned to the left with the summation; what if the first condition were `\sum a_jx_j`? Would you align the `x_j`?

Comment: So you're saying that in the second line `x_j` should be next to the sum? And only the `x_j` in the 2nd and 3rd line should be one under the other, right? If yes, that's how they are aligned in the second answer.

Comment: The conditions contain the same variables, but the alignment is on the conditions, not on the variables. But it's just my opinion. I wouldn't align the variables in any of the line, to be clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this. Use of array

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[paper size={10cm,5cm}]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll@{}ll}
\text{minimize}  & \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m} w_{j}&x_{j} &\\
\text{subject to}& \displaystyle\sum\limits_{j:e_{i} \in S_{j}}   &x_{j} \geq 1,  &i=1 ,\dots, n\\
                 &                                                &x_{j} \in \{0,1\}, &j=1 ,\dots, m
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: `...` should be `\dots`.

Comment: In `array` environment, [lines are vertically too near](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111898/185783), which is sometimes ugly for mathematical equations.

Answer (score 15):

The `=` signs are not quite vertically aligned. Here is a solution with `alignat*` that gives a correct alignment, and has a somewhat simpler syntax. I also propose a variant, where the sums are aligned, and the x_j are only partially aligned, that look better in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[paper size={10cm,5cm}]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
 & \text{minimize} & \sum_{j=1}^{m} w_{j}x_{j}& \\
 & \text{subject to} \quad& \sum_{\mathclap{{j:e_{i} \in S_{j}}}}x_{j}& \geq 1, & i &=1 ,..., n\\
                 && x_{j}& \in \{0,1\},\quad & j &=1 ,..., m
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & \text{minimize: } & & \sum_{j=1}^{m} w_{j}x_{j} \\
   & \text{subject to: }& \quad & \sum_{\mathclap{{j:e_{i} \in S_{j}}}}\begin{aligned}[t]
                    x_{j} & \geq 1,& i & =1, \dots, n\\[3ex]
                  x_{j} & \in \{0,1\}, & \quad j &=1 ,\dots, m
                \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Variant:
[image]

Comment: You can use `\mathclap` for `j:e_{i} \in S_{j}}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Judicious remark. I've modified my code,  but had to move the `&x_j` alignment point to `& \geq` (and similarly `&\in`).

Comment: @HarishKumar: But if the Σ's align, there will be a gap between Σ and  x_j in the second line! Or I didn't grasp well what you mean?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Personally I would have aligned the Σ's and only the x_j's in the last two lines. But so required th O.P…

Comment: @Bernard: When I wrote the question I didn't think about the `\sum` being aligned, I only wanted the text and the `i=` and `j=` to be aligned. But thank you for your response and I will consider aligning the `\sum` as well.

Comment: @Jessy09: I'll add in a moment the variant as suggested in my previous comment

Comment: `...` should be `\dots`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Oops ! That comes  from the O.P.'s  original code, but I didn't notice it, because my editor is configured to display `\dots` as `…`.

Answer (score 3):

Using [optidef](/questions/tagged/optidef) package you can obtain the same result like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}


\begin{document}
\begin{mini*}
{}{\sum_{j=1}^{m} w_{j}x_{j}}{}{}
\addConstraint{\sum_{j:\, e_{i} \in S_{j}} } {x_{j}\geq 1,}{}{\mkern53mu i=1 ,\ldots, n}
\addConstraint{ }{x_{j}}{ \in \{0,1\},}{\quad j=1 ,\ldots, m}
\end{mini*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked beatifully