# How to align a linear program equations that has subequation and equation tags

Tags: equations, numbering, align, subequations

I am using subequations and equation tags so I can number the objective function with (1) and all others constraints with (1a) (1b) and so on. However, the problem is that when I use these tags I don't get an aligning just like the solution on this page: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184937/align-a-linear-program)

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{MCRequation:main}
\begin{equation}
\text{min} \quad  F \left( x \right)  = \sum _{d \in D_{}}^{} \sum _{p \in P_{d} }^{} \xi _{dp} x_{dp} \tag{\ref{MCRequation:main}} 
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
\text{s.t.} \quad
\sum _{p \in P_{d} }^{}x_{dp}= h_{d},  \quad &d \in D \label{MCRequation:d}\\
\sum _{d \in D~ }^{} \sum _{p \in P_{d} }^{} \delta _{dpl} x_{dp} \leq  c_{l}, \quad l \in L \label{MCRequation:c}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225520.

Comment: Unrelated: Note that `\text{min}` is probably not what you want here as it will be italic if the text outside math is italic, probably better to just use `\min`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{MCRequation:main}
\begin{align}
& \text{min}  && F(x) = \sum_{d \in D_{}}^{} \sum_{p \in P_d}^{} \xi _{dp} x_{dp}     &   & \tag{\ref{MCRequation:main}} \\
& \text{s.t.} && \sum_{p \in P_d}^{}x_{dp} = h_d,                                     & d & \in D \label{MCRequation:d}  \\
&             && \sum_{d \in D~}^{} \sum_{p \in P_d}^{} \delta_{dpl} x_{dp} \leq c_l, & l & \in L \label{MCRequation:c}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely how [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225520), which [I linked above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507694/how-to-align-a-linear-program-equations-that-has-subequation-and-equation-tags/507698#comment1282915_507694), does it, and thus the [comment below the more original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225517/subequations-with-main-equation-number/225520#comment557190_225520) applies as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `mini!` environment, from the dedicated package `optidef`, which defines several possible layouts. By default, the objective function part is the first subequation, but you can easily have the parent equation number using `\tag{some number}`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}[2]
 {}{F(x) = \sum_{d \in D_{}}^{} \sum_{p \in P_d}^{} \xi _{dp} x_{dp}\tag{1} \label{MCRequation:d}}{\label{MCRequation:d}}{}
 %
\addConstraint{ \sum_{p \in P_d}^{}x_{dp} = h_d, }{\enspace d \in D \label{MCRequation:d}}
\addConstraint{ \sum_{d \in D~} \sum_{p \in P_d} \delta_{dpl} x_{dp} \leq c_l,}{\enspace l \in L \label{MCRequation:c}}
 \end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.